# Installing tensorflow without internet

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

I want to install tensor flow in an offline machine. (behind firewall for security reasons)

I have already installed conda on the machine. (conda 4.7.12)

I downloaded tensorflow-1.8.0-0.tar.bz2 from https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64/
ran these commands

```
conda install -c conda tensorflow-1.8.0-0.tar.bz2

#results
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

now I open python

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
```

but I get this error

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: I have tried using pip and several combination of wheel file does not work. (2.7 with pip2) . I just need a simple CPU installation. THE SYSTEM IS OFFLINE

Comment: Doesn't Anaconda already have tensorflow?

Comment: Also, you should probably open the firewall to at least conda forge, or proxy / mirror it internally to your network. That would unblock every other python developer in your company

Comment: No it does not. :(. I don't have the privilege to open the firewall. nor Can i get the approvals to do it

Comment: My OS version details are as follows. if some one find the right whl file that I can use that will also help.                                                                          
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.6"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6

Comment: OS shouldn't matter. You can try to find where conda actually puts things on disk to see if things really are installed like the command says

Comment: @Akshay Kadidal, Is your resolved now ? Else, Please can you share the methods that you tried apart from this? So that we will try to assist you. Thanks !

Comment: unfortunately, I have not succeeded. I tried to install it on an m/c on a cloud  "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7" machine. and copy the folders. That did not work either.